# Behavioural experiment on Nasonia Wasps

Tags: entomology, ethology, behaviour, experimental-design, wasps

I want to see how two male Nasonia vitripennis interact with each other. I have been using enamel paint on their heads to distinguish them, but I am wondering if any other methods of marking them would be less invasive. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve previously used Posca pens to mark wasps during experiments - I think that’s going to be about as non-invasive as you can get without using some kind of advanced video tracking techniques. But this was on much larger paper wasps than *Nasonia* which are much smaller.